# CSS Font Awesome v6 Icon won't align within pseudo element correctly

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome v6. I've gotten the icons to appear as they should but I can't get them to align within the ::before element.

Here's an image showing how the icons are appearing:

[image: Here's an image showing how the icons are appearing]

The icons, as you can see, are appearing behind the before element (the circle). The box image indicating a missing image is where the icon should appear (the icon is clearly displaying on the screen so this is not a missing icon issue).

[Here's my code (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/6L7c0j8k/3/)

I've already used the Font Awesome pseudo elements feature on my site to customise the bullet points for a standard `ul` list and it worked fine. The only difference here is that I'm using the `nth-of-type()` selector. It works absolutely fine if I put anything but a Font Awesome unicode in the content.

I've looped through all of the positions and display options on 'Inspect Element' and can't get it to position correctly. The only thing that works is if I manipulate the svg element that is added by the Font Awesome library, which is a bit inconvenient.

I've tried to search Google for solutions but can't find anything except posts which are asking for help to get the images to display in the first place, which is obviously not my issue here.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Everything looks fine once you include the font awesome stylesheet, and remove the script. The script you linked in the js fiddle (`https://kit.fontawesome.com/915c8771de.js`) what does this do? Where does this come from?

Comment: @t.niese That's the Font Awesome library. The icons won't work without it. From v6 they encourage the use of kits instead of hauling in the entire library as you had to do before, so that's what that is

Comment: If you use the kit in v6 it doesn't load the font to display the icon in the pseudo-element, it instead places an SVG at the beginning or end of the element the pseudo-element belongs to. That's actually a really strange way to solve it, especially for dynamic sites. Not sure if you can change that in some way.

Comment: @t.niese I've added the all.min.css file and it still doesn't display correctly on my site. It worked fine when I added it to the Fiddle, but I get the same result as before when I swap out the kit for the Font Awesome files on my site.

Comment: I just copy pasted the code and ran it locally, it is properly aligned! <[image link](https://ibb.co/QYGDg1f)>

Comment: @firstuser So then I can assume that I have conflicting code. Thanks for testing it locally. I'll dig through my css and see where I'm going wrong